# Start workflow again if field was changed

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

How could I loop/restart the WF if one field was changed? Got date field that automatically changes after status is approved. I need to launch same workflow for same item again if date field was changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for some field to change to the particular value in your workflow then you can use **Wait for Field Change in Current Item** action in SharePoint designer workflow.

**Reference**:

1. [Understanding Eventing Actions in SharePoint Designer 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/understanding-eventing-actions-in-sharepoint-designer).

**Note**:

1. According to SharePoint 2013 User's Guide: Multiple instances(for same version) of the same workflow cannot run on a single item at the same time.

Comment: If I understood you correctly. Running workflow over and over for one list item isn't possible?

Comment: Yes, you cannot run the same instance of workflow on list item if already one instance of workflow is running on that particular item.

Comment: Hope it helps. Please accept and upvote if this answer helps you.

Comment: No it didn't. Kinda made WF to trigger again if it was approved, still working on it

Comment: What is the issue now?

Comment: It only relaunches one time and then stuck at waiting for field to be empty when it is empty